# Scanning with StructureMap

Tags: c#, structuremap

A project i am working on uses StructureMap.  We have a code segment using something like this:

```
Scan(x =>
{
    try
    {
        x.Convention<SqlTypesConvention>();
        x.Assembly("ASSEMBLY NAME HERE");
    }
    catch
    {
    }
});

internal class SqlTypesConvention : IRegistrationConvention
{
    #region IRegistrationConvention Members

    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        string interfaceName = "I" + type.Name + "Data";
        Type interfaceType = type.GetInterface(interfaceName);

        if (type.IsAbstract || !type.IsClass || interfaceType.IsNullRef())
        {
            return;
        }
        registry.AddType(interfaceType, type);
    }

    #endregion IRegistrationConvention Members
}
```

What does this Scan and Convention code do?

Comment: http://bit.ly/12gNn5v

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM LOL..I have already read the StructureMap docs on official website but was still not able to understand the Convention thing..and that is why i posted the question here hoping that someone will explain this in simple words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequently the interface for class `Foo` is named `IFoo`. Thus the convention is to prefix the class name with `I`.

The convention in your code sample is that for a given class `Foo` its interface will be named `IFooData`

StructureMap will use this convention to try to find the Interface relationships for all the Types. So, when a class constructor asks for an `IFooData` StructureMap will be able to provide an instance of `Foo`.

Answer (score 1):

If there are any classes "XXX" that use the interface "IXXX" which starts with "I", then the structure map will scans for all the assembly for "xxxx" class and instantiates automatically. Detail information about how structure map works is available @ [how structure map works](http://karthikeyanvk.blogspot.in/2013/04/what-is-dependancy-injection-how.html)